# Regex: capture sentence if string contains certain patterns

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to capture three sub-string from a string, which must contains these three sub-string patterns:

1. birthday (all numbers with yyyymmdd format)
2. ID number (begin with character and followed by numbers)
3. full name

If the three sub-string patterns are not available, it will return no match.

Pattern sample:

```
XD079523 ALFRED ROMEO 19830311
ALFRED BETA GAMMA 19830311 AD929523
BETA FERNANDEZ AS079523 19830311
19830311 BETA MAX  AS079523
KK079523 19830311 ANGEL MARINA VINES
19830121 BX079523 VINCENT EVERHART
```

I already tried the following regex:

```
/(?=.*\b([a-z]{1,2}\d+)\b)(?=.*\b(\d+)\b)(?=.*((?:\b[a-z]+\b\s*)+)).+/mi
```

test: https://regex101.com/r/iypQuC/1

Using the above pattern, I can successfully captures birthday & ID number, not the full name. The pattern only capture the last word from the full name.

Any suggestion on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well the problem is obviously because of [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) in `(?=.*((?:\b[a-z]+\b\s*)+))`. You could just make the `.*` that eats up the desired words lazy by putting `?` after it. I would additonally recommend to refactor that part for better accuracy:

```
^(?=.*?\b([a-z]{1,2}\d+)\b)(?=.*?\b(\d+)\b)(?=.*?\b([a-z]+(?:\h+[a-z]+)*)\b).+
```

- Further made all `.*` lazy `.*?` (also for better performance)
- Added `^` anchor for triggering lookaheads only at start

[See your updated demo at regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/fPJ0Ut/1)

Comment: thank you. I really need to re-learn the "greediness" for sure.